# How do I install the package from github in PyCharm through pip in PyCharm console

Tags: python, github, terminal, pip, pycharm

I am trying to run the following in the Project Console in PyCharm:

```
!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs
```

But the result that I get is:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How do I run the `!pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs`in order for it to be installed?

Answer (score 2):

You need to run from **pycharm terminal**:

`pip install git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs`

or

`pip install -q git+https://github.com/tensorflow/docs`

Comment: Terminal closes a minute or two after I run pip install

Comment: So the `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` is solved. Are the docs installed?